# GDK4: No display available in terminal application

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gdk

I am trying to copy some text to the clipboard in a terminal application using GDK4. As far as I understand, this is done using a clipboard object, which is obtained from a GdKDisplay. However, there seems to be no display available. Here is a MWE:

```
#include <gdk/gdk.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    GdkDisplayManager* manager = gdk_display_manager_get();
    printf("DisplayManager pointer is not null: %i\n", manager);

    GSList* list = gdk_display_manager_list_displays(manager);
    printf("Number of available displays: %i\n", g_slist_length(list));
    g_slist_free(list);

    GdkDisplay* display = gdk_display_get_default();
    printf("Default display: %i\n", display);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
DisplayManager pointer is not null: 95547392
Number of available displays: 0
Default display: 0
```

Consequently, when I try to grab a clipboard using `gdk_display_get_clipboard()`, I obtain an assert error: `Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_display_get_clipboard: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed`

There is a display known to the terminal, the command `echo $DISPLAY` outputs `:0`. Do I need to initialize the GDK library? There used to be an init() function in GDK3, but it seems to have disappeared in GDK4.

Answer (score 0):

`gdk_init()` was indeed removed, but you can just use [`gtk_init()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/gtk4-General.html#gtk-init) to make sure the necessary GDK initialization is performed. After that, you should no longer have a NULL pointer when calling `gdk_display_get_default()` (unless something is wrong with your setup).